# Jquery making div fadeout with timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, fadeout

Looking to make a div fadeout after 10 seconds.

Tried various things but can't get the timer working.

This is the code:

```
$('#deletesuccess').show();
```

Edit:

This is the full code:

```
    function refreshTable() {
        //timestamp to get around ie caching issue
var tsTimeStamp= new Date().getTime();


$('#deletesuccess').show().fadeOut();



$.get('table.php',
      {action: "get", time: tsTimeStamp},
      function(data){
        $('#customertable').html(data).fadeIn();
      });
return true;
}
```

I need to show the div and then hide it after x amount of seconds.

Answer (score 15):

An easy way in 1.4:

```
$('#deletesuccess').delay(10000).fadeOut();
```

You can also abort this easily if needed:

```
$('#deletesuccess').stop(true, true);
```

Answer (score 11):

Use setTimeout for this.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $("#deletesuccess").fadeOut("slow"); 
  }, 10000 );
```

Comment: How would I add that to my function?? I have added the full code above